# Windows Server 2016 - How to isolate a user to only run a specified file.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

I've been searching for a while on how to isolate a designated user to only run a specified .exe file and nothing else. All I want for this new user to see is the desktop , without start button , no right click , no task manager , just the ability to run this one .exe file. I tried with GPO but it's limited on what it can do (can't remove the start button for ex.). Any ideas , any software that does this? Thanks.

Comment: What you want is not realistic.  You can make it so that only a single application can be ran, using an AppLocker rule, if you do this depending on what you block, it will also prevent you from logging into that user.  You can prevent task manager from being used with a group policy.

Comment: What you are requesting is a Windows feature that has a name: Assigned Access! Once configured, it restricts the user to one app only. Except, it is a feature of Windows 10, not Server 2016. See http://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-assigned-access-windows-10

Answer (score 1):

The policy settings under Remote Desktop session host was the thing I needed. Maybe I expressed myself wrong , but the policy allows me to run an .exe file and nothing else , which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) - your expectations are a bit over the top. But I think you're approaching the issue the wrong way.

The way I see it GPO, UAC on max and Default user profile will account for most of your needs. Why blocking start button if you can remove everything from start menu? Same with context menu (right-click).

You can also have a look at Windows Remote Desktop Server or similar - this will actually give you almost exactly what you need.